# why this simple function cause out of gas error on TestRPC?

Tags: solidity, out-of-gas

thanks for any suggestions.

```
function withdraw() public {
    if(votes[msg.sender].voteRound == curRound){
        numTotalVotes = numTotalVotes - votes[msg.sender].numVotes;
        numVoteAddrs--;

        while(votes[msg.sender].numVotes > 0){
            delete votes[msg.sender].voteRecs[votes[msg.sender].numVotes - 1];
            votes[msg.sender].numVotes--;
        }            
        votes[msg.sender].voteRound = 0;
    }
    else{   
        votes[msg.sender].numVotes = 0;
        votes[msg.sender].voteRound = 0;         
    }
```

Comment: How many votes are you processing? What are the types of `votes` and `voteRecs` ? Using storage is expensive, 20k gas write a nonzero value to a zero slot, and 5k gas updating an existing slot.

Comment: votes like this:

Comment: mapping (address => voteRec) public votes; and voteRec like this: struct voteRec{uint32 voteRound; uint32 numVotes; mapping (uint32 => uniVote) recs;} and uniVote is a struct to record a unique vote status to a proposal. it's on coding, just 2 votes, 1 vote has just one voteRec. it's a stranded problem to me.

Comment: The only thing I imagine can cause problem in that function is the `delete votes[msg.sender].voteRecs[votes[msg.sender].numVotes - 1]` if `votes[msg.sender].voteRecs` has less items than `votes[msg.sender].numVotes` that will be an access out of bounds.

If you want to delete the whole array it is possible to replace the loop with `delete votes[msg.sender].voteRecs; votes[msg.sender].numVotes = 0`.